# How to Spinner for loop 01-31 & 2556-2467?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want set Spinner show number 1-31 and 2556-2467

number 01-31

```
    String[] day = new String[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
        day[i] = "" + i;

        BHSpinnerAdapter<String> arrayday = new BHSpinnerAdapter<String>(
                activity, day);
        spinnerDate.setAdapter(arrayday);
    }
```

number 2556-2467

```
String[] year = new String[92];
    for (int x = 0; x < year.length; x++) {
        year[x] = "" + x;

        BHSpinnerAdapter<String> arrayyear = new BHSpinnerAdapter<String>(
                activity, year);
        spinnerYear.setAdapter(arrayyear);

    }
```

How to thank

Comment: for(int x = 2556 ; x > 2467 ; x--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loops as below:

```
// For number 01-31
for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    day[i] = (i<10) ? ("0"+i) : (""+i) ;
}

//number 2556-2467
for(int x = 2556 ; x >= 2467 ; x--) 
{
     year[x] = "" + x;
}
```